# Why does the sum of grouped variables not work?

Tags: r, group-by, sum, aggregate, dplyr

I am trying to sum up the values of a column of a dataframe (*variance*) according to the group they belong to (*Types*). Since there are only three '*Types*' (MRF, OH and SDH), there should be 3 unique values, but I only get 1 unique value (the overall sum of *variance*).
The dataframe I am using (dat_joined) is as follows:

```
IndicatorID AreaName           standardised variance Type     
10401       Hartlepool                0.601   13478. MRF     
13333       Middlesbrough             0.481   10000. MRF
```

I have run this code, which seems to disregard the fact that I have grouped by Type.

```
dat_weighted <- dat_joined %>%
  distinct(IndicatorName, AreaName, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Type)%>%
  mutate(sum=sum(dat_joined[,4]))
```

As a result, I got this(simplified df):

```
IndicatorID AreaName           standardised variance Type      sum
10401       Hartlepool                0.601   13478. MRF     25037
13333       Middlesbrough             0.481   10000. MRF     25037
...         ...                       ...     ...    ...     ...
95555       Barnsley                  0.601      14. HO       25037
96666       Oxford                    0.481       1. HO       25037
...         ...                       ...       ...  ...     ...
93347       Staffordshire             0.250     71.0 SDH      25037
11401       Southend                  0.310     80.1 SDH      25037
```

I would however expect to get different results for each sum, like this:

```
IndicatorID AreaName           standardised variance Type      sum
10401       Hartlepool                0.601   13478. MRF     25000
13333       Middlesbrough             0.481   10000. MRF     25000
...         ...                       ...     ...    ...     ...
95555       Barnsley                  0.601      14. HO         17.
96666       Oxford                    0.481       1. HO         17.
...         ...                       ...       ...  ...     ...
93347       Staffordshire             0.250     71.0 SDH        20.
11401       Southend                  0.310     80.1 SDH        20.
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to specify the unquoted column name instead of `dat[,5]`  BTW, what is `dat`?  With `dat[,5]` it is not keepting the grouping info, and extract the whole column from the dataset

Comment: dat[,5] was a typo, I changed it to dat_joined[,5]

Comment: From the post, the 5th columns seems to the `Type`, which is a character column.  If you need the 'variance' sum, then use `%>% mutate(sum = sum(variance))`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo as well, sorry!

Comment: yes, don't know what happened with that

Comment: @akrun thanks, solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is using `dat_joined[,4]` which will extract the entire 4th column.  Instead of doing that, use unquoted column names within `mutate` and that respect the group structure to calculate the `sum` of the column of interest

```
library(dplyr)
dat_weighted <- dat_joined %>%
                  distinct(IndicatorName, AreaName, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
                  group_by(Type)%>%
                  mutate(sum=sum(variance))
```